# How to input text into htaccess authentication pop up(URL access authentication pop up) user name and password field using ROBOT FRAMEWORK

Tags: automation, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Tried :
Input text into alert: did not work since it is not alert
Press keys None ESF : did not work too, showed sending keys to current browser but the pop up didn't close with escape button.
URL technique : https://id:pwd@url.com : doesn't work somehow,so need an alternative to dismiss it somehow

[example photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YcFd.png)